# List all foreign key constraints that refer to a particular column in a specific table

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I would like to see a list of all the tables and columns that refer (either directly or indirectly) a specific column in the 'main' table via a foreign key constraint that has the ON DELETE=CASCADE setting missing.

The tricky part is that there would be an indirect relationships buried across up to 5 levels deep. (example: ... great-grandchild-> FK3 => grandchild => FK2 => child => FK1 => main table). We need to dig up the leaf tables-columns, not just the very 1st level. The 'good' part about this is that execution speed isn't of concern, it'll be run on a backup copy of the production db to fix any relational issues for the future.

I did `SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys` but that gives me the *name* of the constraint - not the names of the child-parent **tables** and the **columns** in the relationship (the juicy bits). Plus the previous designer used short, non-descriptive/random names for the FK constraints, unlike our practice below

The way we're adding constraints into SQL Server:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserEmailPrefs]  
WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UserEmailPrefs_UserMasterTable_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[UserMasterTable] ([UserId])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserEmailPrefs] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UserEmailPrefs_UserMasterTable_UserId]
GO
```

The comments in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534428/preview-sql-delete-for-records-which-have-on-cascade-constraints#comment18532971_13534428) inspired this question.

Comment: Did you look at `sys.foreign_key_columns`? Also note that you'll need to look up table names and column names in `sys.tables` and `sys.columns` - they're represented by their `object_id`/`column_id` values in most other places, not their names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wiser version of myself stumbles upon a question from the curious, younger version of myself. The answer is

`EXEC sp_fkeys 'Users'`

Hoping me from +40 years drop by this week for some additional words of wisdom for the years ahead :)