# How can I see the result of an update without actually run it

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL server, How can I see the result of an update without actually run it?

( I know there is a way (I used it in the past, but I forgot how) ).

---

**The way I achieved it in the past is not by a transaction or log the result, it was by select the result to a temporary table (I think), somebody know how to do it?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I preview a destructive SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465083/how-do-i-preview-a-destructive-sql-query)

Comment: You could run an `update` within a transaction, print the results in a log and then rollback instead of commit

Comment: create a copy of your database and do your tests

Comment: The way I did it in the past is not by a transaction or log the result, it was by select the result to a temporary table (I think),
somebody know how to do it?

Comment: Are you looking for `SELECT … INTO …` along http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114441/how-to-create-table-using-select-query-in-sql-server ?

Answer (score 2):

Possibilities:

1. run it, without commiting then rollback (but will result in a lock until you rollback), see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms174973.aspx
2. use [BEGIN TRANSACTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx) with [ROLLBACK TRANSACTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299.aspx) and [OUTPUT Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx), according to the following answer:  [How do I preview a destructive SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465083/how-do-i-preview-a-destructive-sql-query) (mentioned by @hatchet and @MarcinJuraszek)

   ```
   BEGIN TRANSACTION
     UPDATE [table] SET [values] OUTPUT inserted.*
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   ```
3. transform you're UPDATE statement to a SELECT statement

Comment: @road242, The way I did it in the past is not by a transaction or log the result, it was by select the result to a temporary table (I think), do You know how to achieve it?