# What is wrong with my stored procedure definitions here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, database-design

I have like 20 errors but I'll list 3 and maybe you can help me understand what I'm doing wrong overall with trying to write stored procedures based on the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx.

Full code:

```
CREATE DATABASE JsPracticeDb; 
/* Create tables corresponding to the problems, solutions to 
   problems, and ratings of problems or solutions */
GO

USE[JsPracticeDb]
Go

/* Table representing JavaScript problems. The promp_code 
   is the HTML that formats the JS code for the view. */
CREATE TABLE Problems 
( 
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    prompt_code VARCHAR(5000) NOT NULL,
    created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

/* Create sprocs for adding and deleting problems */
GO
CREATE PROC AddProblem  
    @prompt_code VARCHAR(5000) 
AS 
    INSERT INTO Problems (@prompt_code)
GO

CREATE PROC DeleteProblem
    @id INT
AS
    DELETE FROM Problems WHERE id=@id
GO  

/* Table representing JavaScript solutions (in formatted HTML),
   associated solvers and code that tests validity of solutions */
CREATE TABLE Solutions 
(
   id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
   problem_id INT NOT NULL,
   solver VARCHAR(50),
   solution_code VARCHAR(5000),
   test_code VARCHAR(8000),
   FOREIGN KEY (problem_id) REFERENCES Problems(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

/* Create PROCEDURE for adding and deleting solutions */
GO
CREATE PROC AddSolution
    @problem_id INT,
    @solver VARCHAR(50),
    @solution_code VARCHAR(5000),
    @test_code VARCHAR(8000)
AS  
    INSERT INTO Solutions (@problem_id, @solver, @solution_code, @test_code)
GO

CREATE PROC DeleteSolution 
    @id INT 
AS
    DELETE FROM Solutions WHERE id=@id

/* Table representing 0-5 star rating of associated solutions */
CREATE TABLE Ratings 
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    solution_id INT NOT NULL,
    stars TINYINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (solution_id) REFERENCES Solutions(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
/* Create sproc for adding ratings */
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE AddRating
    @solution_id INT,
    @stars TINYINT 
AS
    INSERT Into Ratings (@solution_id, @stars)
GO

/* Table representing comments on solutions or comments on coments, and
   the associated commenter. The association of comments on comments is 
   mapped in the next table, CommentPaths   */
CREATE TABLE Comments 
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    solution_id INT NOT NULL,
    commenter VARCHAR(50),
    cmnt VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
    created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (solution_id) REFERENCES Solutions(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

/* Create sprocs for adding and deleting comments 
CREATE PROCEDURE AddComment
    @solution_id INT NOT NULL,
    @commenter VARCHAR(50),
    @cmnt VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
    @parent_id \
AS 
    INSERT INTO Comments (@solution_id, @commenter, @cmnt)
   Still implementing   
*/

CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteComment 
    @id
AS 
    DELETE FROM Comments WHERE id=@id
GO

/* Closure Table for comment tree, e.g.

                         Comments
    ==================================================
    id | solution_id | commenter | comment | created
    --------------------------------------------------
    1  |    1        | ......... | .....   | ......
    2  |    1        | ......... | .....   | ......
    3  |    1        | ......... | .....   | ......
    4  |    1        | ......... | .....   | ......    
    5  |    2        | ......... | .....   | ......    
    6  |    2        | ......... | .....   | ...... 


                      CommentPaths 
                ========================
                 ancestor | descendant
                ------------------------
                    1     |     2
                    1     |     3 
                    1     |     4
                    2     |     4
                    5     |     6

corresponds to the Comments ids being related
to each other like

                1       5
               / \      |
              2   3     6
             /
            4

 */
CREATE TABLE CommentPaths 
(
    ancestor_id INT NOT NULL,
    descendant_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ancestor_id, descendant_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (ancestor_id) REFERENCES Comments(id) ON CASCADE DELETE,
    FOREIGN KEY (descendant_id) REFERENCES Comments(id)
);

/* sproc called on delete of a comment to delete descendant comments
   The references to the descendant comments in CommentPaths */
GO
CREATE PROC DeleteCommentDescendens  
    @AncestorId INT 
AS 
    /* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506602/best-way-to-work-with-transactions-in-ms-sql-server-management-studio */
    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT descendant_id FROM CommentPaths WHERE ancestor_id=@AncestorId AS descs
        DELETE FROM Comments WHERE id IN descs
        DELETE FROM CommentPaths WHERE ancestor_id IN descs OR descendant_id IN descs
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT 
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
            ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
            ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
            ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
            ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
            ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

The first 3 errors are

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure AddProblem, Line 20
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure AddSolution, Line 46
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure AddRating, Line 66
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

which refer to the lines

```
INSERT INTO Problems (@prompt_code)
```

and

```
INSERT INTO Solutions (@problem_id, @solver, @solution_code, @test_code)
```

and

```
INSERT Into Ratings (@solution_id, @stars)
```

respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a number of syntax errors:

In `AddProblem`:

```
INSERT INTO Problems (@prompt_code)
```

should be:

```
INSERT INTO Problems (prompt_code) VALUES(@prompt_code)
```

---

In `AddSolution`

```
INSERT INTO Solutions (@problem_id, @solver, @solution_code, @test_code)
```

should be:

```
INSERT INTO Soulutions (problem_id, solver, solution_code, test_code) VALUES (@problem_id, @solver, @solution_code, @test_code)
```

---

In `AddRating`

```
INSERT INTO Ratings (@solution_id, @stars)
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO Ratings (solution_id, stars) VALUES (@solution_id, @stars)
```

---

In `DeleteComment`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteComment
    @id
```

should be

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteComment
    @id INT
```

---

In `CommentPaths` table creation:

```
FOREIGN KEY (ancestor_id) REFERENCES Comments(id) ON CASCADE DELETE
```

should be

```
FOREIGN KEY (ancestor_id) REFERENCES Comments(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

---

In `DeleteCommentDescendens`

```
SELECT descendant_id FROM CommentPaths WHERE ancestor_id=@AncestorId AS descs
DELETE FROM Comments WHERE id IN descs
DELETE FROM CommentPaths WHERE ancestor_id IN descs OR descendant_id IN descs
```

should be:

```
DECLARE @descs AS TABLE(descendant_id INT)

INSERT INTO @descs(descendant_id)
    SELECT descendant_id FROM CommentPaths WHERE ancestor_id=@AncestorId

DELETE FROM Comments WHERE id IN (SELECT descendant_id FROM @descs)
DELETE FROM CommentPaths WHERE ancestor_id IN (SELECT descendant_id FROM @descs) OR descendant_id IN (SELECT descendant_id FROM @descs)
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm getting `Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DeleteComment, Line 100
'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.
Msg 1767, Level 16, State 0, Line 139
Foreign key 'FK__CommentPa__ances__108B795B' references invalid table 'Comments'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 139
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.` Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Try adding `GO` before and after the procedure declaration. As for the other error, I'll leave it to you as an exercise. =)

Answer (score 0):

Are you new to T-Sql Programming?
If that's the case I would suggest you to go through documentation or learning material to go about the syntax.

The problem in your case is you need to mention the list of the columns or match the columns that values should be inserted for.
Further you run into a problem if you add a new column to the table then what will you do?
It might work for you, but if somebody else needs to maintain and enhance the code it will not make an iota of sense to him/her.

So I will suggest that you explicitly mention the column names barring the identity columns and the defaults that you have
e.g:

```
    CREATE PROC AddProblem  
       @prompt_code VARCHAR(5000) 
    AS 
       INSERT INTO Problems(prompt_code) values(@prompt_code)
    GO
```