# What is the best way to update two tables at the same time in SQL?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have two tables. one is "Data" and another one is "AnalyzedData"

Two tables are for, first table "Data" is used to store basic data and another table to store details about analyzed data.

In "Data" table we have 3 columns - "DataID","DataName","AnalyzedDataID" (foreign key to "AnalyzedData")
in AnalyzedData table we have 3 columns. "AnalyzedDataID","AnalyzedataName"

Initially we have data in DataID and DataName colums. Later, after analyzing the data, We are inserting data into AnalyzedData table. So we need to update the AnalyzedDataID in Data table after inserting data into AnalyzedData table.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using SQL Server 2008 or later, OUTPUT clause can be pretty helpful in your scenario. You can insert data in your "Analyzed Data" table, which will generate an ID, which can be captured with the help of OUTPUT. Then that ID can be used to update your "Data" table.

Refer [Implementing the OUTPUT Clause in SQL Server 2008](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/implementing-the-output-clause-in-sql-server-2008/) for more details on how to use the OUTPUT clause.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to start a transaction in your stored procedure. If any of the insert/updates fails, you rollback the transaction; otherwise, you COMMIT the transaction. So the recipe is:

```
1. Take the parameters you need in the stored proc
2. Start a transaction
3. Insert/Update each table independently
4. If no error, Commit the TRANSACTION; otherwise, ROLLBACK
```

Some useful links:

[Intro to Transactions](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions)

[Best way to work with Transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506602/best-way-to-work-with-transactions-in-ms-sql-server-management-studio)